# Why is fab in fragment not responding to click events?

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I have added a floating action button to a fragment held in an activity. When the user clicks on it, a new activity should be launched, but nothing happens.

Here is the fragment layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             tools:context="com.neutronstar.revu.fragment.FeedFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/review_recycler_view"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_review_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the fragment class:

```
public class ReviewFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.add_review_fab) FloatingActionButton mAddReviewButton;

    private OnReviewNext mListener;

    public ReviewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public interface OnReviewNext {
        void finishReview(String description);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_review, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        mAddReviewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddReviewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnReviewNext) {
            mListener = (OnReviewNext) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnReviewNext");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
}
```

Why is the fab not responding to the click events, should this be handled by the activity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A suggestion- You can use databinding and avoid findViewById . Anyway try debugging and also log  something in onClick

Answer (score 0):

Try to add click event in xml file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_review_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:onClick="floatBtnClicked"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

Then add it to activity

```
public void floatBtnClicked(View v) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check project-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
  }
}
```

Check module-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}


 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View calcView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, calcView);

        return calcView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.mAddReviewButton)
    public void one() {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        result.setText(result.getText().toString() + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_review, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    mAddReviewButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewByID(R.id.addReviewFab);

    mAddReviewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddReviewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were 2 FAB.One is on Activity, and another one on fragment. Check is there FAB on activity. Fragments's FAB was under the activity's FAB and did not receive any touches